# How does taking 2 archetypes in from the same core class work?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, archetype

In the APG it states;

> A paladin could, however, be both an undead scourge and a warrior of the holy light, since none of their new class features replace the same core class feature.

So does that basically mean that this PC would be a multiclass Undead Scourge/Warrior of the Holy Light?

Does the leveling/skill/feat acquisition work just like any multiclass character?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Such a character would still be a Paladin, with their Smite Evil, Aura of Resolve and Aura of Justice features altered by Undead Scourge, and Aura of Faith and spellcasting altered by Warrior of the Holy Light. Otherwise, they function like a normal Paladin for all of their Paladin levels. They can multiclass out of Paladin as normal.

This is because archetypes alter the features of a class, rather than act as classes of their own. If archetypes were to act as unique classes, the restriction on replacing class features would be out of place.

Comment: Oh ok, so archetypes are literally properties of the original class and not meant to function as classes themselves.  Thanks for clearing this up for me!!!